# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found, but is missing another required class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

EAR package is deployed to WAS8.5.5.7. UI can display. However, when UI tries to trigger Java function, I get below response.

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [rrbapp]: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found, but is missing another required class.

SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.

SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path

SRVE0234I: Application class path=[/opt/WebSphere85/profiles/appprofile/installedApps/wascell/abcapp.ear/cn-abc-web-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/classes:
/opt/WebSphere85/profiles/appprofile/installedApps/wascell/rrbapp.ear/cn-abc-web-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/cn-abc-domain-1.0.0.jar:
/opt/WebSphere85/profiles/appprofile/installedApps/wascell/rrbapp.ear/cn-abc-web-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/cn-abc-db-object-1.0.0.jar:
/opt/WebSphere85/profiles/appprofile/installedApps/wascell/rrbapp.ear/cn-abc-web-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/cn-abc-web-1.0.0.jar:
/opt/WebSphere85/profiles/appprofile/installedApps/wascell/rrbapp.ear/cn-abc-web-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:
....
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a Jar dependency error, have you tried running `mvn clean install`, it should resolve your issue.
Run  this command and try redeploying again

Comment: I have tried "mvn clean install" for my project, and then build ear package to deploy to WAS server again. But it appears the same error message. Is is possible to relate to any jar conflict between my package and WAS server? It can work in local Eclipse. The same EAR package can also work in Tomcat server. But can not work in WAS server.

Comment: Yes bcz of server library difference

Comment: Could you advise which jar file may lead to this "DispatcherServlet" problem? spring-web, spring-webmvc? or others?

Answer (score 0):

After adding "slf4j-log4j12" jar in my package, it can work without this error. I think the reason is, log can not print without this jar in server, so the program stop at the beginning.